# Remove permissions inheritance for current list item using Workflow 2010

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, office-365, designer-workflow

I'm trying set unique permissions on the current list item and then remove permissions inheritance for item through a workflow.

How to achieve the above task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add an impersonation step to get elevated priviliges. In this step you will notice some extra actions for changing permissions.

The "replace permissions" action allows you to replace all existing permissions with a set of your own. This automatically breaks permissions.